# What's the point in passing I/O as parameters?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ Primer, Fifth Edition; and I still don't get it what's the point of passing a reference to a stream in the `Sales_data` class

```cpp
Sales_data(std::istream &is)
```

Why do this if you can just use `std::cout` and `std::cin` explicitly?

Comment: So that you can pass in other kinds of streams, such as `ifstream`s.

Comment: `cout` isn't the only output stream.  What if you want to send the data to a file, or a printer?

Comment: Side note: Streams cannot be copied. That leaves you forced to pass them by some sort of reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to pass `std::cin` to such a function. You can also pass `std::ifstream` to read from a file, or `std::istringstream` to read from a string, and so on.

Comment: I see. So if that's the case, how can one identify whether the passed arguments is `std::ifstream` or `std::istringstream` or just a standard `std::cin`/`std::cout` if they have different functionally, so is there a way to detect it? or is it better to use `std::ifstream` explicitly as parameters if you want it? or the detection doesn't matter?

Comment: @RenzAguirre, ideally it shouldn't matter. You can implement your function such that it does not matter.

Comment: @RSahu Trying to detect what kind of stream you got is a smell of bad design. You can do it with `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`, yes, but there's almost never a good reason to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do this if you can just use `std::cout` and `std::cin` explicitly?

As a software design and implementation principle, it's better to have functions that don't use any hard coded objects and/or values.

When you make the `std::istream` object as input argument to the function, the function becomes flexible. The calling function(s) can decide whether they want to read the data from, which can come `std::cin`, a `std::ifstream`, a `std::istringstream`, etc.